# close items in listview in android java

Tags: android, listview

I create a listview with two item. The first item is TextView(for the title) and second is a table (for a child). When I click on the TextView, the table is visible.
I click TextView1 then table 1 is open, then I click TextView2 and table2 are open, but table 1 does not close. I want to close table 1 then open table 2.

I get the title and child from database in data adapter class.

Comment: Post your code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

i have a solution:--

1. take a int instance variabe (suppose i).

   take adapter reference as Instance variable.(suppose adapter)
2. in setOnItemClickListener of listview :--

   ```
   setOnItemClickListener(_ int position_ _ _){

   // do something 

    i=position;

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
   ```
3. in getView() method of adapter :--

   ```
   public View getView(_ _ _ _ ){

   // do something

   if(i==position){

    table.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);

   }else{

   table.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
    }
   }
   ```